# SQLite - multiple calls in same transaction

Tags: typescript, sqlite, capacitor

Thanks for looking -
I'm writing a front end SPA in Typescript. I'm using capacitorJS for cross platform compatibility, and I'm using the @capacitor-community/sqlite plugin.
I'm new to SQLite, but not to databases in general.

This may be complicated by using a specific API over SQLite.
The API is here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/sqlite#supported-methods

Regardless, the API is not matching my expectations.

I want a pattern of being able to start a transaction, make multiple calls, and finally commit the transaction (or roll back in an error handler). It would be great if I can make calls to read within the same txn, or at least be able to read *outside* the txn while the write txn is open.

It looks like this (capacitor-community/sqlite) wrapper is adding a transaction around each call I make, by default, unless I override with a bool parameter. If I override, I'm responsible to include the transaction code in the sql statement block.

My first, naive approach was to issue a statement that would start a transaction, it would then make additional api calls that are supposed to be part of the txn, and finally run a sql statement that would `commit` the txn.
e.g.

```js
async Transaction(actions: () => Promise<void>): Promise<void> {
    await SqliteService.Instance.db.execute('BEGIN TRANSACTION;', 
    try {
      await actions();
      await SqliteService.Instance.db.execute('COMMIT TRANSACTION;', false); //useTransaction = false
    } catch (e) {
      await SqliteService.Instance.db.execute('ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;', false); //useTransaction = false
      throw e;
    }
```

This didn't work at all. It appears state like that isn't kept between calls. I think some things (like having an open cursor) would cause the session to remain open, but normally the session would just open and shut with each call I make to the API.
*I have not tried doing tricks with e.g. cursors to keep the transaction open, this seemed like an anti pattern*

As I mulled it over, it seems I may have to send one big block of SQL within a transaction to get SQLite to do what I want.

So I'm considering rewriting my documentStore api to, instead of directly calling SQLite to run statements, instead when I want to do multiple things in a single transaction, to provide a sqlBuilder type class. Then I could glue multiple statements together.

...

But I like with the current interface, and rewriting the 'write' methods on my documentStore to have something of a sqlBuilder seems like a big step in a different direction.
e.g.

```js
async Transaction(sqlBuilder: (builder: WriteSqlBuilder<T>) => {statement: string, values: unknown[]} []) {
...
```

I'd like to know - how do people usually approach performing multiple actions (queries, writes) in SQLite within a single transaction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, this ended up being some peculiar behavior in the wrapper I was using `capacitor-community/sqlite`.

When making calls to e.g. `executeSet({sql, params}[], transaction)` you can pass a boolean to use a transaction or not. This is a helper.
This `transaction` value defaults to true.  When it's set true, the wrapping library automatically adds `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION` (and `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` in case of error) around your sql items for you, all in the single call.

If you explicitly set `transaction` to false, it'll behave as vanilla SQLite would, starting an implicit transaction for the call, and when the call is finished, that's the last SQL statement, the implicit transaction is implicitly committed.

What tripped me up is I'm doing my dev work in a web browser (for this cross platform application), so I'm using `jeep-sqlite`. `jeep-sqlite` uses an in-memory sqlite db, and has a `saveToStore(dbName)` method to flush the SQLite bytes into an IndexedDb entry.

I think what was happening is I was flushing within the middle of the transaction. After flushing, there was no long an active transaction.

---

In the end I'm using `async-lock` around my access to the SQLite db wrapper, and have my own `async Transaction(actions: () => Promise<void>)` method that handles the BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK itself, and some general purpose DocumentStore methods that make calls that are implicitly then included in the transaction.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for the mention of saveToStore -- I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out why an initial database create/populate wasn't persisting and that did the trick!